# redirect request to folder except for specific request

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess that redirects all requests to a folder (public folder for laravel framework) and now I have a staging app that is clone from the main application e.g. `mydomain.com/staging` and I wanted to access the staging folder to run the staging application but it returns me **404**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

and below is the htaccess of /public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/staging` subdirectory? What does this `.htaccess` file contain? What is generating the 404? Apache? The "main application"? Or, the "staging" application?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, I have htaccess also on /staging and its the same htaccess on the above, pointing to public folder of laravel framework

Comment: And "What is generating the 404?". Providing you have the appropriate `.htaccess` file in the `/staging` subdirectory then you shouldn't have to do anything in this regard - you do not need to add an "exception". You must also have additional `.htaccess` files in the `public` subdirectories - presumably these don't have a hardcoded URL-path? However, your URLs now obviously contain `/staging` - so this will need to be accounted for in your routing (in your application).

Comment: @MrWhite it simply returning 404 not found due to all request being forwarded to /public folder so if you access /staging folder, it will be forwarded to /public folder that has htaccess also. Kindly see my updated post for the additional htaccess on /public folder